# Autofac IComponentContext - resolving databse instance using entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, windows-services, autofac

I have UI and windows service application which access the same database, but I noticed recently that when I push some object to the database using UI, the windows service simply doesn’t see them. The way I’m accessing the database is the same in both cases, using Autofac IComponentContext:

```
IEntitiesDb db = _componentContext.Resolve<IEntitiesDb>();
```

Furthermore, sometimes, even inside the windows service, when one class reads the data and passes a list of objects to the another class (where I again resolve IEntitiesDb instance) that manages them and saves the changes into database, the first one won't be aware of these changes next time it is called.

Comment: This seems way more about how EF is handling data persistence than it is about how you're accessing the database context. You may want to update your question title to get more EF folks looking at the question.

Comment: How is IEntitiesDb registred in the container?